# is it necessary to clear timeout on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can you please help me to tell `is it necessary to clear timeout on button click  in react ?`
I have a example I want to show a alert on button click.here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-torvalds-e84hq?file=/src/App.js

```
  let id;
  const onclick = () => {
    // first way
    id = setTimeout(() => {
      alert("---");
    }, 0);
    // is it required ?
    //clearTimeout(id);

    // second way without clear
    const second = setTimeout(() => {
      alert("---");
    }, 0);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("-----", id);
      // is it required ?
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });
```

which way is better way ?

**If I don't clear timeout on button click is there any performance issue ?.If there any memory leak if I don't clear timeout on button click**

Comment: It will just always exist as timeouts are added to the window element. (until page refreshes) which is technically a memory leak... performance will only start to be affected if the button is clicked multiple (hundreds/thousands) times... But it is still best practice generally.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to clear the timer if you don't want the timer callback to be called — if you want to *cancel* the timer callback. In fact, if you uncommented the code you've shown, the callback would be cancelled immediately and the `alert` would never happen.

If you don't want to cancel the callback, no, there's no need to clear the timer. The resources associated with it are released when the timer call is made; the browser automatically gets rid of its entry in the timer list.

Comment: thanks . but if the component unmount ? will i need to clear timerout

Comment: @user944513 - It depends entirely on whether you want to cancel the timer callback if the component is unmounted. If you're setting state in the callback, yes, you do want to cancel. If you aren't, it's up to you.

Comment: thanks I understand. but if you see my example https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-torvalds-e84hq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't see any difference when I click `show button` it mount my component and add click which show alert using timeout.I don't see any difference after cleartimeout or with cleartimeout

Comment: is there any memory leak if i not cleartimeout

Comment: @user944513 That's because the timeout is set to `0`, so you don't have a chance to unmount the component before the event triggers. If you change the timeout to something like `2000` (2s) and you press "show" again after setting the timer you will only trigger the second event handler, because the first one got cleared.